# Qt Ellipse Border Thins Out

Tags: c++, qt, border, ellipse

I am trying to draw an ellipse in Qt and the border on the edges goes thin in some places.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 3));
painter.drawEllipse(event->rect());
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

When painting a shape with an outline, you have to factor in the width of the pen.  So in your case, change to this:

```
// Adjusted by 2 pixels because half your pen width is 1.5, but QRect is
// for integer types, so rounded up.
painter.drawEllipse(event->rect().adjusted( -2, -2, 2, 2 ) );
```

Comment: @congard, I would suggest to post the error in signs as a comment first (so the community and the OP can first (dis)agree) and to post the extra info and general case as a new answer. You may refer to and upvote the original answer.